# QFileInfo::absoluteFilePath() not working?

Tags: c++, qt

I am using Qt 4.7.4. I have a relative file path that I am storing as a QString and I want to later convert it into an absolute file path. However, when I create a QFileInfo object from that QString and call absoluteFilePath(), the path is still not absolute. For example:

```
QString fn = "..\..\..\..\..\..\App\exampledata\doll\everything-F.wrl";
QFileInfo fi(fn);
QString fn2 = fi.absoluteFilePath();
```

And now fn2 contains "C:/../../../App/exampledata/doll/everything-F.wrl", while I want it to contain "C:/App/exampledata/doll/everything-F.wrl". I could manually remove the useless dots, but that's tedious.

Comment: Are there enough directories to balance out all the `..` entries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not the function you should be calling if you want a canonical path. You should be using  [`QFileInfo::canonicalFilePath`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qfileinfo.html#canonicalFilePath) instead.